# How to only show main menu on sticky menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been looking up into how to do the sticky menu and have checked many tutorials. I also checked some related questions here but there seems to be view answers and it still doesn't work on my end. I would like to do one without the plugin. is that possible?

this is the code i found on one of the tutorials. I followed the tutorials but it doesn't seem to let the menu stick.

these are the codes I added on my original file::

on html file:

```
<!--sticky menu-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<!--ends here-->
```

on css:

```
.fixed{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;

}

nav{
    z-index: 500;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.nav-placeholder{
    margin: 0 0 40px 0;
}

.fixed .nav-inner{
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.fixed .nav-inner-most{
    max-width:700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

the js script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    // define variables
    var navOffset, scrollPos = 0;

    // add utility wrapper elements for positioning
    jQuery("nav").wrap('<div class="nav-placeholder"></div>');
    jQuery("nav").wrapInner('<div class="nav-inner"></div>');
    jQuery(".nav-inner").wrapInner('<div class="nav-inner-most"></div>');

    // function to run on page load and window resize
    function stickyUtility() {

        // only update navOffset if it is not currently using fixed position
        if (!jQuery("nav").hasClass("fixed")) {
            navOffset = jQuery("nav").offset().top;
        }

        // apply matching height to nav wrapper div to avoid awkward content jumps
        jQuery(".nav-placeholder").height(jQuery("nav").outerHeight());

    } // end stickyUtility function

    // run on page load
    stickyUtility();

    // run on window resize
    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        stickyUtility();
    });

    // run on scroll event
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

        scrollPos = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

        if (scrollPos >= navOffset) {
            jQuery("nav").addClass("fixed");
        } else {
            jQuery("nav").removeClass("fixed");
        }

    });

});
```

summary:
http://jsfiddle.net/misaki03/9gtk9x7r/1/

I hope someone could help me out here.

I have edited this, because i was wondering what this code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

on the tutorial I'm following, is for. I followed the site demo and saw this line of confusing codes. (I made it a link coz the code was too long)

http://learnwebcode.com/tutorial-files/sticky-navigation/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js

I am not sure what is it, but it worked. The menu is now on sticky mode. however, it is showing the sub menu as well as I scroll it down. is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Codepen http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/avqVVd?editors=010

Are you looking for something like this? You just had some `z-index` issues that were getting in the way of things i feel like plus a few script errors.

Here is a cleaner version of stickymenu

```
function stickIt() {

  var orgElementPos = $('.original').offset();
  orgElementTop = orgElementPos.top;               

  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= (orgElementTop)) {
    // scrolled past the original position; now only show the cloned, sticky element.

    // Cloned element should always have same left position and width as original element.     
    orgElement = $('.original');
    coordsOrgElement = orgElement.offset();
    leftOrgElement = coordsOrgElement.left;  
    widthOrgElement = orgElement.css('width');
    $('.cloned').css('left',leftOrgElement+'px').css('top',0).css('width',widthOrgElement).show();
    $('.original').css('visibility','hidden');
  } else {
    // not scrolled past the menu; only show the original menu.
    $('.cloned').hide();
    $('.original').css('visibility','visible');
  }
}
```

Comment: I kinda don't get what you're saying. I tried the code though but it doesn't work. The error I am having is the sub menu appearing once the sticky menu is shown or activated

Answer (score 0):

after trying to find different source, i was able to fix the issue with the help of Amit. I saw this question and figured it somehow resembles my needed code and tried it out. i tweaked it a little though

here is the reference link:

[sticky navigation with submenu and smooth scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29231925/sticky-navigation-with-submenu-and-smooth-scroll)

i just added the codes he mentioned on his jfiddle and it worked on me, thanks @Amit and the owner of the question

Answer (score -1):

sticky is a new value introduced for the CSS position property. This value is supposed to behave like position: static within its parent until a given offset threshold is reached, in which case it acts as if the value was fixed.

```
.menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #bffff3;
    position: sticky;
 }
```

checkout this link :http://www.sitepoint.com/css-position-sticky-introduction-polyfills/
it might be helpful.
Good luck

Comment: the code for sticky menu works for me now, its just that, the sub menu links appears as well. @sanam Javidnia